# How do I apply the uniform boundedness principle to this problem?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have a measurable set $E$ and a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $L^p(E)$ such that for all functions $g\in L^q(E)$, with $q$ the conjugate index of $p$, $\displaystyle\int_{E}f_ng$ is bounded. I have to show that the sequence $f_n$ itself is bounded in $L^p(E)$.

This problem appears in Royden's analysis book and I get that I need to apply the uniform boundedness principle. I've started out by considering the family ${f_n}$ as a family of operators from $L^q\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb R}$ taking $g\in L^q$ to $\displaystyle\int_{E}f_ng$. I know that this is bounded for all $g$ in my domain. However, I don't get how to apply the result of the uniform boundedness principle after this. The principle itself allows me to conclude that $\displaystyle \sup_{n,\lVert g\rVert_q=1}\displaystyle\int_{E}gf_n<\infty$. How do I get to $\lVert f_n\rVert_p$ is bounded from here? I think I'm making some mistake.  I tried Holder's inequality, but I don't seem to be able to finish the proof.

Comment: Hint: The mapping $\Phi:L^p \to (L^q)', f\mapsto \left[g\mapsto \int fg\right]$ is an isometry. What is $\sup_{\|g\|_q = 1}\int gf_n$?

Comment: Got it, thank you. Had to use both uniform boundedness and the fact that $L^q$ and $L^p$ are duals.